# How to use sshpass?

Tags: command-line, ssh

I need to use `sshpass` to launch a remote command through SSH from a Java code.

If I manually type in a console:

```
ssh -p 22 user@ipaddress mplayer '/media/data/myFavouriteSong.mp3'
```

works perfectly, but asks for password. So I tried running `sshpass`:

```
sshpass -p mypass ssh -p 22 user@ipaddress mplayer '/media/data/myFavouriteSong.mp3'
sshpass -p mypass ssh -l user@ipaddress mplayer '/media/data/myFavouriteSong.mp3'
sshpass -p mypass ssh -t user@ipaddress mplayer '/media/data/myFavouriteSong.mp3'
sshpass -p mypass ssh user@ipaddress echo 'OK'
```

and none of them work.

Comment: Did you setup passwordless login? Password-less logins with OpenSSH
http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152

Comment: I'd rather stick to sshpass, due to the inconvenients of enabling password-less login in an enterprise

Comment: Did you try this: sshpass -p 'mypass' ssh username@server.example.com

Comment: I did, doesn't matter if i use 'mypass' or mypass. It starts waiting forever

Comment: sshpass -V works?

Comment: It prints: "This program is free software, and can be distributed under the terms of the GPL. See the COPYING file for more information". And then ends its execution and does nothing else (I tried adding -V to the beginning of the command I was handling, not just typing sshpass -V)

Comment: What error/problem were you seeing? Does `sshpass -v` tell you what's going on?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This may be caused by the host-key checks done by `ssh`. It looks like `sshpass` keeps silent on invalid host keys (no output on neither `stderr` nor `stdout`) and exists with status-code `6`. At the time of this writing, this was revision 50, and the matching constant in the code is [`RETURN_HOST_KEY_UNKNOWN`](http://sourceforge.net/p/sshpass/code/50/tree/trunk/main.c#l50), which hints to that error.

Your error-code may differ and looking at the code linked above may give you some insight.

*If* your issue is an invalid host-key you should think twice about overriding the error with a CLI option. **Your machine could be compromised or you may be subject to a MITM attack!** If you are 100% certain that this is not the case and if you have no means to keep the verified host-keys up-to date, you can use a command like this:

```
sshpass -pfoobar ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host command_to_run
```

Comment: With the brew install, a space is needed after -p. https://github.com/hudochenkov/homebrew-sshpass

Comment: NOTICE:  Everyone should remember that it is more secure to use passwordless SSH Host Keys whenever possible!  By definition, using SSHPass is less secure.

Comment: @Questionmark while that is true, there are edge-cases where the remote endpoint does not support authentication via key. Which is where sshpass comes in handy

Comment: Yes, I know.  That is why I said "whenever possible"...

Comment: _"In my case StrictHostKeyChecking=no is necessary ..."_ - This completely bypasses the check if you are talking to the right server. You could be talking to a malicious host, and anything you send over SSH (**including the password**) becomes compromised. And you wouldn't even notice it. There may be situations where this is necessary, but you should not provide that option in an answer that does not require it.

Comment: @marcelm You are absolutely right. I completely reworded the answer to properly warn about the potential issue.

Comment: Awesome, have a +1 :)

Comment: With new enough SSH, there's [`StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new`](https://askubuntu.com/a/123080/158442).

Comment: @exhuma: there are no such edge cases (otherwise post link) where SSH host keys cannot be used. It might be a obsolete very old version of SSH that should never be used, as it is full of unfixed security holes. sshpass is only used by people that are clueless about how you can use crypto keys to safely log into a Linux system, that are used to this dumb Windows system where you will store a password in a file somewhere. Please please read this: https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/ and become a more professional admin! Both more secure and better.

Comment: @MarkusBawidamann yes there are edge-cases. I work with older hardware network devices which support SSH for remote management. They are located in an isolated network and SSH is only used for mgmt. Their main function is too critical to warrant a replacement/upgrade and they don't support key-based logins. Providing a link would quite likely be in violation of an NDA. In my 20+ years of sysadmin work this is the first time I came across this issue (hence why I mentioned them as *edge* cases). So instead of attacking my experience you should do some research first yourself.

Comment: @exhuma: I have done the research, I have a lot of experience and have never come across this and am most shocked that hardly an article mentions that this is really horrible for security: ssh should never used that way, as it defeats the whole secure aspect of it. But of course it is a free country, you can use whatever you want.

Answer (score 11):

`sshpass` command works only if the password prompt ends in `assword:`.

If your password prompt is different you may have to adjust the source code of `sshpass` to recognize the prompt you have.

I have seen password prompts like  `Password for user@host:` on some systems, maybe this is your problem.

Comment: sorry? `-P prompt     Which string should sshpass search for to detect a password prompt`

Comment: This new option (needs at least V1.0.6 of sshpass) solves that problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry. This kind of issue (solution?) happen so often, old questions that are already fixed at new versions. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think you want something like:

```
sshpass -p yourpassword ssh user@ipaddress somecommand
```

For instance, this works for me:

```
sshpass -p mypassword ssh username@10.0.0.9 touch foo
```

Comment: if pass contains all type of special characters then it will not works

Answer (score 2):

1. make a key

   `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
2. make a .ssh folder on the remote server it will ask for a password

   `ssh $USER@SEVERNAME mkdir -p .ssh`
3. copy the key to the remote server

   `cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh $USER@SERVER 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'`

---

Check if it asks for a password, if not it should work.

```
ssh $USER@SEVERNAME 'command'
```

Answer (score 1):

sshpass syntax is

```
sshpass [-ffilename|-dnum|-ppassword|-e] [options] command arguments
```

Note that there is no space between the -p and the password.

Also I've noticed that you have to connect with ssh at least once manually to obtain the RSA key of the machine you are connecting to, to go into the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file before sshpass will allow you to connect.

so after obtaining the entry in the known_hosts file I can run a command such as

```
sshpass -ffilename_with_password_in_it ssh user@server uname -a
```

and it will execute the command `uname -a` on the remote server and output the results to the standard out on the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

There is lots of way to do that, here is my suggested solution:

First of all, **storing your password** in a variable is give you more flexible commands. `sshpass` has an option for that:

`-e`: this option allows to read password from `$SSHPASS` environment variable

You have two way to set this variable:

1. Set directly in your code:

   ```
   export SSHPASS='your_pass'
   ```
2. Or ask for it:

   ```
   readPassword () {
     echo Ssh Password: 
     read -s SSHPASS
     eval "export SSHPASS='""$SSHPASS""'"
   }

   # read password

   readPassword
   ```

Than execute your command;

1. If your command is static, run it directly:

   ```
   sshpass -e ssh user@host << EOF
   mplayer '/media/data/myFavouriteSong.mp3'
   command2 parameter1 parameter2 parameter3 ...
   command3 parameter1 parameter2 parameter3 ...
   ...
   EOF
   ```
2. If your command will be dynamic use like this:

   ```
   DYN_FILE_LOC='/media/data/myFavouriteSong.mp3'

   eval 'sshpass -e ssh user@host << EOF
   mplayer "$DYN_FILE_LOC"
   command2 parameter1 parameter2 parameter3 ...
   command3 parameter1 parameter2 parameter3 ...
   ...
   EOF'
   ```

hope this helps someone.

Comment: In your readPassword function, can't you just do export SSHPASS?

Comment: @kutschkem, I trust but my idea that i think here; i dont want to write my pass in a static file but instead of writing password again and again for lots of servers(7+), i write once :) You don't have to use `readPassword` function, you can just write your password, it should work :) Only i want to share my code which is shows an example using  `sshpass` for dynamic commands :D

Comment: No, I just mean that the eval is not necessary after the read, export does not need an assignment. http://ss64.com/bash/export.html

Comment: the problem with -e is that the export will be listed in your history

Answer (score 1):

@exhuma had an example that lead to it working for me.

The password needs to be in form of `-pPassword` (without the space)

also quotes may be necessary: `sshpass -p'Password&0' user@hostname`

Answer (score 0):

`sshpass` uses pseudo terminals and the `man` page includes apologies for breaking occasionally.  You can also try `fd0ssh`.  It works if you do not need to send `stdin` to a process on the remote machine.  That works if you just issue a command and capture the result.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `-f -t -t -t`

```
sshpass -p$PASS ssh -f -t -t -t $USER@$HOST $COMMAND
```

Additionally you might have to remove "requiretty" from sudo config (/etc/sudoers) on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest usage is to set the SSHPASS variable:

```
read -p "SSH password:" SSHPASS
export SSHPASS
```

Then you can run e.g.:

```
sshpass -e ssh $user@$host echo Test
```

If something is going wrong, the `-v` flag will give you more information.